# How can I use Reddit as a traditional RSS feed aggregator?

Tags: rss, reddit

I love Reddit's interface, I'd like to use Reddit to access the feeds that I normally use Google Reader for. How can I treat arbitrary RSS feeds, such as BBC News and ycombinator, like subreddits?

Answer (score 1):

From a technical standpoint of the site [Reddit.com](http://reddit.com) there is no way to do this. There may be RSS feed aggregators out there that have a similar interface, but Reddit cannot be used to view RSS feeds.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can create your own subreddit and automatically post everything from a rss to that subreddit.

https://github.com/gavin19/reddit-rss-bot for example does this